# Function of human kidneys

Tags: kidney

Why are the kidneys called metanephric? What does the term metanephric actually mean? I tried to search that on Google but couldn't find the exact meaning.

Comment: Start with mammalian kidney development: http://www.els.net/WileyCDA/ElsArticle/refId-a0001152.html

Answer (score 2):

There are [metanephric diseases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metanephrogenic_blastema), which refer to the location of pathologic tissue relative to the main kidney mass, but unless someone with more expertise wants to weigh in, I don't think that kidneys themselves are called metanephric.

There is also a developmental stage of the kidneys, in which they are referred to as [metanephros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidney_development#Metanephros). Perhaps you're thinking of that?